# Saving and Loading a model vs updateClassifier in WEKA

Tags: java, classification, weka

I want to know if the weka updateClassifier is doing the same thing as saving/loading a model ?

weka.core.SerializationHelper.write();
weka.core.SerializationHelper.read();

For incremental buildup not all classifier have the updateClassifier(); option.
I know Naive Bayes and only few other classifiers in weka have this option.

In that case for other classifiers is it possible to build an incremental classifier (or retrain a classifier) just by saving a model after each iteration and loading it and retraining it on new data and saving it again ?

Thanks For any insights

Comment: Without having tried it myself, I guess there is a good reason only certain classifiers implement `UpdateableClassifier` (and if you compare the number of implementing classes, you will notice, that it's only a small fraction of all available classifiers). While it is easy to update a nominal Naive Bayes model, or a KNN "model", this is in contrast not the case for neural nets or decision trees. "Updating" a model for the latter generally involves re-training with the whole data.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I am doing, adding some additional instance to the training set and rebuilding the model and saving it and then loading the model and training it on the updated training set.    Hope that would be similar to the UpdateableClassifier where it can rebuild models by only adding one instance at a time.